# is there any way where i can apply group and pagination using createQuery?

Tags: rethinkdb, feathersjs, feathers-hook

Query like this,

http://localhost:3030/dflowzdata?$skip=0&$group=uuid&$limit=2

and dflowzdata service contains data like,

[
  {
    "uuid": 123456,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "uuid": 123456,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "uuid": 7890,
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "uuid": 123456,
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "uuid": 4567,
    "id": 5
  }
]

Before Find Hook like,

```
if (query.$group !== undefined) { 
  let value = hook.params.query.$group
  delete hook.params.query.$group
  const query = hook.service.createQuery(hook.params.query);
  hook.params.rethinkdb = query.group(value)
}
```

Its gives correct result but without pagination, like I need only two records but its give me all records

result is,

```
{"total":[{"group":"123456","reduction":3},{"group":"7890","reduction":1},{"group":"4567","reduction":3}],"data":[{"group":"123456","reduction":[{"uuid":"123456","id":1},{"uuid":"123456","id":2},{"uuid":"123456","id":4}]},{"group":"7890","reduction":[{"uuid":"7890","id":3}]},{"group":"4567","reduction":[{"uuid":"4567","id":5}]}],"limit":2,"skip":0}
```

can anyone help me how should get correct records using $limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation on data types](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/data-types/), *ReQL commands called on `GROUPED_DATA` operate on each group individually. For more details, read the `group` documentation.* So `limit` won't apply to the result of `group`.

[The page for `group`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/group/) tells: *to operate on all the groups rather than operating on each group [...], you can use `ungroup` to turn a grouped stream or grouped data into an array of objects representing the groups*.

Hence [`ungroup`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/ungroup/) to apply functions to `group`'s result:

```
r.db('db').table('table')
.group('uuid')
.ungroup()
.limit(2)
```