# How do I get json data with retrhinkdb

Tags: node.js, date, express, group-by, rethinkdb

(I'm not good eng.)
I use a group to include dates. I want to get the information out in a row. What do i need to do

```
.group(r.row('time_create').dayOfWeek())
```

json export

```
    [
        {
        group: 1,
        reduction: [
        {
        detail: "no",
        id: "37751c10-97ea-4a3a-b2c9-3e8b39383b79",
        order_id: "15",
        status: "Not_Delivery",
        time_create: "2018-09-23T15:25:13.141Z"
        }
       ]
      }
   ]
```

i want change data json to

```
{
  "date":
  {
    "Sun": [
      {
            detail: "no",
            order_id: "15",
            status: "Not_Delivery",
            time_create: "2018-09-28 15:25:13"
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Do i have to give the information out as i want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried but didn't manage to transform the data from your previous question. ;)

Here is a proposition, this is not the only way of doing it.

First, it seems you want to remove the `id` field. You may do that in your ReQL using [`without`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/without/):

```
.group(r.row('time_create').dayOfWeek()).without('id')
```

(You may apply `without('id')` before `group`, it should work the same, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537063/is-there-any-way-where-i-can-apply-group-and-pagination-using-createquery/52551438#52551438) for more details.)

Then, to transform the result array (let's call it `queryResult`) into an object (let's call it `output`):

```
// prepare the skeleton of the output
let output = {
  date: {}
};
// walk the result, filling the output in the process
queryResult.forEach((groupData) => {
  let key = groupData.group;
  if (!output[key]) {
    output[key] = [];
  }
  output.date[key].push(...groupData.reduction);
})
```

Now you almost have your desired structure in `output`, the only thing is that day keys are still numbers and not a short day name. In my opinion, this should be handled by the front-end, since you may want to have different languages implemented for your front-end. But anyway, the idea is always the same: having a translation table that maps Rethink's day numbers with human-readable day names:

```
const translationTable = {
  1: 'Mon',
  2: 'Tue',
  // ...
  7: 'Sun'
};
```

Now if you do that in your front-end, you just replace the data's keys on the fly, when displaying is needed (or retrieve the key from the day name, depending on how you display stuff). Otherwise, if you go for a back-end implementation (which, again, is clearly not the best solution), you can change one line in the code above (assuming you declared `translationTable` already):

```
let key = groupData.group;
// becomes
let key = translationTable[groupData.group];
```

Feel free to ask in comments if there's something you don't understand!